# Unity3D 2018 OnInspectorGUI getAssetPath not working

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've recently upgraded my Unity from 5.6 to Unity2018.4.6f1, In my project I have a script which is called "ConstantCollection", the script has an editor script (ConstantCollectionEditor) which has an OnInspectorGui override of Editor.
The method contains only these 3 lines:

```
ConstantCollection col = (ConstantCollection)target;
string assetPath = AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(col).ToLower();
Debug.LogError(assetPath);
```

Upon creating a prefab, and attaching the ConstantCollection component to it, the code runs and prints out an **empty string**.
According to documentation, an empty string or null is only returned in case the asset does not exist, but obviously the asset exists.
Furthermore, this code piece was working flawlessly previous to the version update.
Can anyone shed some light on the matter?

I will add that instead of trying to get the asset path this way, I also tried extracting the guid of the object and using the utility to get path from guid, but for some reason the guid returned from the asset is "000000000000000".

Comment: Asset file may not exist yet (?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day of fiddling around with various things I've found the reason of the issue and the solution.
First the reason - 
Since I upgraded to Unity2018.4.6f1, the "prefab view" feature is added, it seems (I did not know that) that when opening a prefab with "prefab view" Unity actually creates an Instance of the prefab for the view and does not use the actual prefab, therefor when using the target in OnInspectorGUI method, it actually references an instance of the prefab and not the prefab itself.
Regarding the solution - 
After roaming the unity documentation a lot and realizing that Unity refers to the prefab view as its own stage I've managed to solve the issue using the following substitution of an experimental library unity has:
This is the original implementation:

```
ConstantCollection col = (ConstantCollection)target;
string assetPath = AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(col).ToLower();
Debug.LogError(assetPath);
```

This is the new implementation:

```
ConstantCollection col = (ConstantCollection)target;
string assetPath = (UnityEditor.Experimental.SceneManagement.PrefabStageUtility.GetPrefabStage(col.gameObject)).prefabAssetPath.ToLower();
Debug.LogError(assetPath);
```

This change locates the actual prefab from the prefab stage's instance and gets a reference to it and then you can simply fetch the asset path for it.
Hope this saves some time to people in the future.